# When I press the icon, I want the matter in the area I stepped on to disappear with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-hooks

```
const [todo,setTodo] = useState([]);

const removeTodo = id => {
const removedArr = [...todo].filter(item => item.id !== id);
setTodo(removedArr);
};




<div className="todoList">
{todo.map((item, index) => (
<div className="todoTarget" key={index}>
<span className="todoSpan">{index+1} - {item}</span>{" "}
<div>
<FaTimesCircle onClick={() => removeTodo(item.id)}/>
</div>
</div>
))}
</div>
```

My code snippet is like this, when I click on the icon, all the items disappear, not the item in the icon I clicked. What is the reason. I would appreciate your help.

I tried to freeze it with the map function in the arrays and solve it with the id of each item, but they all disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such things usually happens when you don't have a unique id for every object in the list.

Check if every item in your todo list has a unique id, in case not then add one. should work just fine.

check my example with your code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-https-pyr1ie?file=/sr